# Need Auto Custom Sort Code Using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula

I need data to sort automatically when entered into excel.

Custom sort data by 5 variables: Expired, Pending, New, Grace Period, Current

I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("B1:B" & lastrow), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    
    End If
End Sub
```

I am having trouble customizing this.

Comment: Record a macro while performing the sort and add that into your code.